# Browser support of nextnonce directive in HTTP digest authentication

Tags: c++, http-authentication, digest-authentication

I've done a C++ based HTTP server (or to rephrase - spilled another drop in the ocean) and encountered an issue with HTTP digest authentication.

According to the [HTTP authentication RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) using the `nextnonce` directive in the `Authentication-Info` header is a valid way of implementing a single use nonce mechanism. I've done this according to the RFC but both Chrome and Firefox seem to ignore the directive and issue all further requests with the initial nonce thus triggering unneeded 401 responses. An example illustration with Firefox:

First request - my server returns 401 and issues the initial nonce `a1f778b2afc8590e4a64f414f663128b`
[image]

Firefox successfully authenticates and gets a reply with the `Authentication-Info: nextnonce="0b72e74afbcab33a5aba05d4db03b801"` header
[image]

Firefox issues a new request to fetch image from the returned html - still the initial nonce `c1587dd7be6251fa715540e0d6121aa5` is used and thus a reply with a new nonce and a flag that the provided nonce is expired is sent back.
[image]

Same scenario as for the first image request.
[image]

Now authentication succeeds with the new nonce.
[image]

The authentication succeeds for the second request as well.
[image]

As can be seen in the images - even though I reply with `Authentication-Info: nextnonce="0b72e74afbcab33a5aba05d4db03b801"` upon a successful authorization on the first request the next two requests still use the original nonce instead of the provided `nextnonce` value. Has anyone had a similar experience? I am most certainly doing something wrong - even though the RFC says that the client **SHOULD** reply with the provided `nextnonce` value and thus it is not mandatory I highly doubt that the most popular browsers do not use this technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's a known Firefox bug that's been open since 2001.

[Bug 150605 - digest authentication problem: Mozilla ignores the nextnonce parameter of Authentication-Info Response Header.](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=150605)
which is a duplicate of
[Bug 116177 - next nonce digest auth test fails](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=116177)

Comment: Thanks, this was something very valuable. However I get the same issue with Chrome, but I'll scan their bug database to see if they have a pending bug too.